# Using map to get all values from input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say there are numerous `<input>` and I wanted all the values as an array. I thought it'd be really easy to just do `$("input").map(function(obj) { $(obj).val() })`, but when I get that, I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')`

This error is occuring within `jQuery` itself here:

```
var rreturn = /\r/g;

jQuery.fn.extend({
    val: function( value ) {
        var hooks, ret, isFunction,
            elem = this[0];

        if ( !arguments.length ) {
            if ( elem ) {
                hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];
                ...
```

Any work around? Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvbgo94f/1/

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @kiner_shah updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` inside map to access that particular element.

```js
$("#a").val("1");
$("#b").val("2");
inputs = $(".test").map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
});
console.log($(inputs));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test" id="a" />
<input class="test" id="b" />
<input class="test" id="c" />
```

Comment: interesting... do you know why `map` passing & using each `obj` as i was doing fails?

Comment: @james, there are two ways to use `map` - [first way](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [second way](https://api.jquery.com/map/). I used second way.

Answer (score 0):

A bit different than what you're looking for, but the standard way to handle this is to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

If you wrap your inputs in a form element:

```
<form>
  <input name="a" />
  <input name="b" />
  <input name="c" />
</form>
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
const formData = new FormData(
    document.querySelector('form')
);

for (const [key, value] of formData) {
  console.log({key, value});
}
```